# Digest Authentication with Xamarin Android AndroidClientHandler

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, digest-authentication

I am trying to do a digest authentication with Xamarin Android AndroidClientHandler but it "Un Authorized - 401" (StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized') error. This is the code that I am using. From the Xamarin documentation I understand that AndroidClientHandler supports Digest Authentication. Any help here is appreciated.

```
//Sample code in the Droid project
        var networkCredentials = new NetworkCredential("dummyuserId", "dummyPassword");
        var droidClientHandler = new AndroidClientHandler { Credentials = networkCredentials, AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip, ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic };

        using (HttpClient oClient = new HttpClient(droidClientHandler))
        {
            //var iTimeout = 
            //oClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, iTimeout);

            //Set Content Type
            oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

            // Setting the required header for the service. 
            oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(ApplicationConfigurationConstants.C_ACCOUNT_UNIT_HEADER, GetAccountingUnit());
            oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(ApplicationConfigurationConstants.C_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN_HEADER, szAuthenticationToken);

            oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


            var oContent = new StringContent(szObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            //Call Service
            var oResult = await oClient.PostAsync(url, oContent);
            //Get Result, if succeeds
            if (oResult != null && oResult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var szResultContent = await oResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return szResultContent;
            }
        }
```

We have verified this service via a .net client and it works. Infact this service was working with the default HttpClientHandler in Xamarin. we stared getting the below error after changing to AndroidClientHandler

*"StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 05:56:11 GMT
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerpool_MT_Q_HHComm_30483=1862543370.4983.0000; path=/, TS013bbd7d=015e9dc2ca1e7a8720c0a49375a536c268624e8007810ada8f06b25d0a925a09448b0985b0b3ae98e8ac88b8217d3148626d7bd2ee; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly
WWW-Authenticate: Digest qop="auth",algorithm=MD5-sess,nonce="+Upgraded+xxxxx",charset=utf-8,realm="na01.xxxxx.xxxx"
X-Android-Received-Millis: 1488347771526
X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 401
X-Android-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1488347764923
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii, text/html
Content-Length: 1293
"*

**I even tried providing a custom implementation based on this post. Still no luck. 
[How can I enable NTLM and TLS 1.2 with Xamarin on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735964/how-can-i-enable-ntlm-and-tls-1-2-with-xamarin-on-android)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on the latest Xamarin build? Xamarin Cycle 9 dropped yesterday which includes updates to its TLS 1.2 support. I am wondering if you could be seeing these errors for not using Boring SSL for your TLS implementation. The details on configuring can be found here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.1/#TLS_1.2_support_in_WebRequest

For your project, you will want to add the following to your project.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AndroidTlsProvider>btls</AndroidTlsProvider>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Additionally, have you verified the URL and authentication works via browser on the same device you are running in the app?

Could you also provide the diagnostic build output and a trace of the error so we know more of what the actual exception is?